# Extracting contours from image to local folder

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to extract contours from image to local folder(image contains  circle shaped contours in a tray)

I have done thresholding and drawing of contours.but not able to extract detected contours into a folder because they are very close in try (like a basket having a number of balls)
example image: https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/donut-balls-on-metal-tray-white-1307503597?src=xfk0YUuijFGMUXsPIcYEPA-1-49

```
count = 0   
for file in sorted(glob.glob(image_path)):

        img = cv2.imread(file)
        #img = imutils.resize(img, width=500)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, 0)

        cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

        seg_c = 0
        for c in cnts:
            seg_c = seg_c + 1
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            roi=img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
            cv2.imwrite(cropped_path + '/frame%d_crop.jpg', roi)
  # cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(200,0,0),2)
count += 1
```

I expected all the detected circle shaped contours extracted to the folder

Comment: What does: "but not able to extract detected contours into a folder" mean? Are you getting errors? Is nothing saved into the folder without errors?

Comment: no errors, contours are not extracting properly.